# Ao imprimir o resultado de uma função, é mostrado "None"

Tags: python

Gostaria de saber porque o retorno de `None` dentro do `print`.

Por acaso não poderia ter usado as variáveis antes?

```py
x = int(input('a'))
y = int(input('b'))

def soma (x,y):
    if x >= 0:
        print('É possível!')
    else:
        print('Não é possível')

print(soma(x,y))
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Como explicado no link indicado acima no box azul, se uma função não retorna nenhum valor (ou seja, não tem nenhum `return alguma_coisa`), então o retorno acaba sendo `None`. Se era pra função retornar algo, coloque o `return`. Se era só pra imprimir e não retornar nada, o último `print` é desnecessário, bastaria apenas chamar a função: `soma(x, y)`

Answer (score -1):

Para que o resultado de uma função seja atribuído a uma variável ou a um parâmetro de outra função, você precisa que ela tenha retorno, ou seja, no corpo da sua função deve ter `return ALGUMACOISA`. Exemplo:

```py
x = int(input('a'))
y = int(input('b'))

def soma (x,y):
    return x + y

print(soma(x,y))
```

No print será exibido o valor da soma entre `x` e `y`.